# PySpark code raises: TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number

Tags: python, pyspark

I have the following piece of PySpark code that has always worked fine, except today:

```
row_stats = dataframe
                 .withColumn("exploded" , explode(col("products")))
                 .withColumn("score", col("exploded").getItem(target_field))
                 .where(col("score").isNotNull())
                 .select(mean_(col("score")).alias("mean"),stddev_(col("score")).alias("stddev")).first()

mean = 0
std = 0
if row_stats is not None:
    print "row_stats.mean"
    print row_stats.mean
    mean = Decimal(float(row_stats.mean))
    std = Decimal(float(row_stats.stddev))
```

I got the error at the line `mean = Decimal(float(row_stats.mean))`:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

The`print` outputs:

```
<type 'NoneType'>
None
```

How to properly handle this error in order to get `mean` and `std` equal to 0?

Comment: Does the code (exactly as in the question) "compile"? shouldn't it be `row_stats.mean()`?

Comment: @CristiFati: Yes, it compiles. It was running all days well. I got the error only today.

Comment: @CristiFati: I made some updates in the question.

Comment: To get you past the error: `mean = Decimal(float(row_stats.mean or "0"))`, but the logical error lies in the expression above which might not do what you think it does.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the dataframe before calling `first()`? Replace the `.first()` with `.show()`. What is the output?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pandas,

Try `row_stats.mean()` instead of `row_stats.mean`

Also the .mean() method default is a columnwise operations, without seeing the rest of your code, based on the variable name you might want to consider subbing in `row_stats.mean(axis=1)`

Comment: OP is not using pandas. `row_stats` is a `pyspark.sql.Row` (or perhaps a list of them), not a pandas DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

This should work with **Pyspark** by casting your **mean** object to decimal:

```
row_stats.mean.cast('decimal')
```